# how to reference facsimile (Turabian style guidelines)

Tags: citations

I have a book that says on the copyright page:

> Wipf and Stock Publishers 
>   . . . 
>   Publication date: 2/23/1999 
>   Previously published by Hunt & Eaton, 1890

It appears to be a facsimile copy, rather than a mere reprint (as I understand those terms; in other words, it looks like they scanned the original and republished it). How should I reference it? I'm supposed to conform to Turabian, but I think Chicago is OK (maybe). I could do:

```
Hunt & Eaton, 1890; facsimile, Eugene, Oregon: Wipf and Stock Publishers, 1999
```

or

```
Hunt & Eaton, 1890; reprint, Eugene, Oregon: Wipf and Stock Publishers, 1999.
```

or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facsimiles of a Printed Source (note that the use of hanging indents applies except for the first one where Title and Facsimile are both left-aligned:

Title. Hunt & Eaton. Newly Re-printed. Original City: Printed by Orig Printer …[for] Original Author…, 1890.
Facsimile, Introduction by Name (Facsimile/Reprint Title). Eugene, Oregon: Wipf and Stock Publishers, 1999.

Or

Title. Facsimile edition by Hunt & Eaton. Eugene, Oregon: Wipf and Stock Publishers, 1999. An explanation, sentence, such as the document appears to be a facsimile circa 1890.

Turabian gives an example related to a musical score; however the order of the citation can remain. A manuscript score reproduced in a facsimile that is part of a multi-volume set. Combine 17.1.3, 17.1.4, 17.1.8 and 17.6.4:

[Dowland, John]. "Flow My Teares Fall from Yo'r Springs." Manuscript score. Oxford, Christ Church Ms. 439, [pp.] 6-7. Facsimile reprint in English Song 1600-1675: Facsimiles of Twenty-six Manuscripts and an Edition of the Texts. Edited with introductions by Elise Bickford Jorgens. Vol. 6, Manuscripts at Oxford, Part I. New York: Garland Publishing, Inc., 1987.

APA gives an example of a reprint:

Freud, S. (1961). The ego and the id. In J. Strachey (Ed. and Trans.), The standard edition of the complete psychological works of Sigmund Freud (Vol. 19, pp. 3 - 66). London: Hogarth Press. (Original work published 1923)